# What does mean "computer-adaptive"?

Tags: meaning

The test is not **computer-adaptive**. Each test taker receives items that cover the full range of ability.

Comment: Have you Googled the term? This is what I found at the top of the search results: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computerized_adaptive_testing

Comment: Thanks. It is the answer that I needed. Please make a response so I accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will find Wikipedia's page on [computerized adaptive testing (CAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computerized_adaptive_testing) helpful:

> Computerized adaptive testing (CAT) is a form of computer-based test that adapts to the examinee's ability level. For this reason, it has also been called tailored testing. In other words, it is a form of computer-administered test in which the next item or set of items selected to be administered depends on the correctness of the test taker's responses to the most recent items administered.